# Find count of WordPress users by role and search string for user name

Tags: users, search, user-roles, wp-user-query

I want to get the total number of results after searching WordPress users by role and a string that matches the user name.

What I tried so far:

```
$args= array('echo'=>false, 'role' => 'author', 'search'=>$search_txt);
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$auth_count= $user_query->get_total();
```

But it returns 0 everytime.

**Note:**

Perhaps it can be done by:

```
$args= array('echo'=>false, 'role' => 'author', 'search'=>$search_txt);
$auth_count= count(get_users($args));
```

or by querying with

```
global $wpdb;
```

But is there any more resource friendly method?

Comment: Your first code looks ok to me. Docs don't specify but perhaps role is case sensitive, try 'Author' if that's what your role is called. And are you 100% sure you have users that will match `$search_txt`. I'm not sure what else would explain getting zero results unless it really is zero results for your search ;-)

Comment: Nopes... Neither 'Author' nor 'author' works. Its the same. I'm searching with $search_txt='sun', and there are users with names like 'Sunita', 'Sunheri'.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

`$search_txt` replaced by `esc_attr($search_txt).'*'`:

```
$args= array('echo'=>false, 'role' => 'author', 'search'=>esc_attr($search_txt).'*');
$user_query = new WP_User_Query($args);
$auth_count= $user_query->get_total();
```

Comment: Ah yes, well spotted. The docs say 'search (string) - Searches for possible string matches on columns. Use of the * wildcard before and/or after the string will match on columns starting with*, *ending with, or *containing* the string you enter.'

Comment: Thank you @mozboz

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer here for reference for anyone searching for WP_User_Query stuff:

As per [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) The `search` field on `WP_User_Query` uses `*` for wildcard text search, and will search on `login`, `nicename`, `email` and `URL`, unless specified otherwise.

E.g. to match any name containing `bob` you need:

```
$args = array(
    'search'         => '*bob*'
);

$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
```